# If one categorical and continuous feature have relation with each other, is it ok to do ordinal encoding?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, feature-selection

[Area vs sales price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPnp4.png)

In the above graph, we can see that there is some relationship exits between area and sales price.
is it ok to do label encoding for the area column.

like data["area"]=data["area"].replace({"T nagar":1,"anna nagar 2"})

I tried to do encoding for the area column, but confused what encoding technique to use like whether should i go for label encoding or one hot encoding.

Comment: The only relation here is that every area *has* a sales price, and you ordered the areas by that sales price. Your question doesn't seem to make sense, or have much to do with categorical encoding?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.